# Why my javascript code not process from top to bottom coding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Why my javascript code not process from top to bottom coding ?

https://jsfiddle.net/p47f6Lcy/1/

With my code when press on `id="test"` Why still `alert` before change `backgroundColor` and `translate3d`

See on my code it's should change `backgroundColor` and `translate3d` before call function `test2_fn`

How can i do for change `backgroundColor` and `translate3d` befire  `alert` ?

..

```
<div id="test" onclick="test_fn()">
CLICK
</div>

<script>
function test_fn(){
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.getElementById("test").style.transform = "translate3d(500px, 0px, 0px)";    
    test2_fn();
}

function test2_fn(){
    alert("555");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Because the browser doesn't repaint the screen until the current JS finishes executing. So the element styles *have* been updated in the DOM, you just don't see it yet.

Comment: how can i do ? for solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) mentioned in the comments:

> Because the browser doesn't repaint the screen until the current JS finishes executing. So the element styles have been updated in the DOM, you just don't see it yet.

If you really want to do it, you can postpone the execution of the other function to the next cycle in the event loop. You can simply use `setTimeout(test2_fn, 0)`.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lq9326c/)

[This](http://timnew.me/blog/2014/06/23/process-nexttick-implementation-in-browser/) is also a good read.

Answer (score 1):

Because it uses a stack to be cleared before **rendering** the changes.
In order to clear the stack you need to make all *statements* to be executed.
I have added a little timeout **10ms** so that *altert* could occur.

```js
function test_fn(callback){
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.getElementById("test").style.transform = "translate3d(500px, 0px, 0px)";    
    
}

function test2_fn(){
  setTimeout(function(){ alert("555");},10) ;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" onclick="test_fn(test2_fn())">
CLICK
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that the browser doesn't repaint the page before invoking the alert.

the following might do the trick:

```
    <div id="test" onclick="test_fn()">
CLICK
</div>

<script>
function test_fn(){
    document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.getElementById("test").style.transform = "translate3d(500px, 0px, 0px)"; 
    setTimeout(test2_fn,20);
}

function test2_fn(){
    alert("555");
}
</script>
```