# Memory Game - how to get both card images to display before the alert pops

Tags: javascript

I have written code for a memory game in JavaScript. My problem is that I can't figure out why both cards selected don't show before the alert (saying that hooray they are the same/or no they don't match) pops up. I am confused because the alert is in the isMatch function which is run after both cards are clicked (isTwoCards function).

```
var isTwoCards = function(){
    if (this.getAttribute('data-card') === 'king') {
        this.innerHTML = '<img src="King.png" class = "myImgClass" alt="King"/>';   
    } else {
        this.innerHTML = '<img src="Queen.png" class = "myImgClass" alt="Queen" />';
    }
    cardsInPlay.push(this.getAttribute('data-card'));
    if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) {
        isMatch(cardsInPlay);
    }
};

var isMatch = function() {
    if (cardsInPlay[0] !== cardsInPlay[1]) {
        alert('Sorry, try again.');
        cardElement.className = "";
    } else {
        alert('You found a match!')
    };
    cardsInPlay = [];
}
```

Here is the entire code: http://codepen.io/Lupeman/pen/GNgXrm

Any help would be greatly appreciated because it's driving me nuts! I'd like to do it without JQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my javascript code not process from top to bottom coding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337451/why-my-javascript-code-not-process-from-top-to-bottom-coding)

Answer (score 1):

You would want to delay the `isMatch` checking until the UI finish updating and the user already done mouse up.

```
if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        isMatch(cardsInPlay);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Elfan! Thank you so much. It has been bothering me for ages and all the solutions i tried to find were soo complicated and almost always involved JQuery. Thank you for your simple answer - very much appreciated!